# Prevent Application changes breaking API

Tags: api, wcf-web-api

I have an application which I am currently writing an API. This is the first time I have created an API from start to finish and have read lots of good articles and how to do this. However a lot of that material focuses on the API development specifically (as it should) but have not found anything that touches on how to ensure the API doesn’t get broken by changes which happen within the application project.

My application consists of a ASP.NET MVC web app which makes calls to a Service Layer to undertake CRUD like operations. So to get a list of all the users in my app the MVC app calls the service layer and asks for them and is presented with a collection of users. My API (WCF Web API) also uses this service layer internally and when I request a list of users, again I get back a collection of users (JSON, XML etc).

However if for some reason another developer changes the underlying User domain object by renaming a field say surname to last name then this potentially is going to break my API as the Service Layer is going to return to my API a user object with a new field name when its expecting something else. My API does in fact have its own representation of objects which get mapped to the application objects when requested but this mapping will not map the surname property and will be returned as null.

Therefore do all changes in the app have to be strictly controlled because I provide an API? If so then do you have to change your app and API in tandem? What if changes are missed? The aforementioned doesn’t seem correct to me hence my post to seek greater knowledge.

Again I’m quite new to  this so any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are owning the API design and you don't really want anyone to pollute your design. Introduce dedicate DTOs for your API use. Which be mapped from the underpinning domain models. But your presentation (via xml or json) won't change even underlying models change frequently.

Comment: That's exactly what I have done but did not want to go into great detail as my question was already quite long. I have a UserDto returned from my Service Layer which maps using Automapper onto my UserApi object. This provides me with some decoupling however as mentioned if my UserDto object properties change I need to update my mapping. However this could possibly go unchecked if a lot of devs working on the code, hence why the question. What I'm understanding from both answers is that you must check that app changes don't break you API. If they do update mapping or new version of the API.

Answer (score 2):

It is inevitable that your application will evolve, if you can create new versions of an API as you applications evolve and support the older versions, then give notice of when older APIs will become obselete.

Comment: Thanks Mark, so what you are saying is that with every application change a new API version should be created reflecting those changes. Then to support the Old API I would need to map the new last name property to the OLD API User's surname property so that it still works. What would happen if a property in the application object was deleted instead of modified? Do software dev teams impose rules on code changes to an application when its linked to an API?

Comment: The API reflects functionality of the application, I guess if fields are made obselete, they could be set as empty rather than removed, so you dont break other applications.